# Disconnecting clips in Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: final-cut-pro

I had a small video project where I needed to make a mosaic of a handful of different videos. I just wanted them all to play on a loop (they're not all the same duration). I dropped videos into the timeline, stacked on top of each other, and transformed, cropped, and scaled them to the right positions. But the stacked clips are all connected to the main clip, and it causes problems when I try to duplicate a clip; FCPX really doesn't make it easy to keep that copy on the same layer as the source.

I'd like to just have my stacks without connections. Is there any way to disconnect them, and prevent them from connecting next time I paste a copy of a clip? Everything I find online is about moving a clip out of the main timeline while leaving connected clips in place, which is *not* what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, maybe you could provide pictures. The whole point of FCX is not having tracks/layers. There are probably another way to do what you need.

Comment: @MateusRibeiro I can't show the content of this video, unfortunately. But it's a bunch of video clips all playing simultaneously, mosaicked. AFAIK the only way to do that is to stack them in tracks and layers.

Comment: It sounds like a job for After Effects, or Motion if you are trapped with Apple software. I don't mean the content, just images of the timeline and what you want to do with the clips.